# Loading X Y data for GNU Octave for the polyfit function

Tags: vector, octave

My data set consists of a number of lines, each line having an X- and Y- coordinates. For example:

```
0.132 1.43
0.138 0.54
0.271 1.12
.
.
.
```

I need to be able to load the above data such that I get two column vectors, one for X-coordinates and one for Y-coordinates, so that the first X-column vector looks like `[0.132, 0.138, 0.271, ...]` and the second Y-column vector looks like `[1.43, 0.54, 1.12, ...]`.

How can I do it?

Comment: Check the `dlmread()` function

Comment: @PierU I am aware about `dlmread()`, yet I not so confident about syntax how I get the first column in variable, say, `xs` and the second column in, say, `ys`.

Comment: `A=dlmread(...)` will by default return a Nx2 matrix (N lines, 2 columns). You will refer to first column by `A(:,1)` and to the second column by `A(:,2)`. It is also possible to parameterize `dlmread()` to return some selected columns only, but in your case it would be mean reading twice the file.

Answer (score 1):

I think that the easiest way is to have those data in a text file, as in your example: the first column is the x coordinate and the second is the y coordinate.
Assuming you saved the text file as "coord.txt", in your octave script, write the following lines lines:

```matlab
load coord.txt
x=coord(:,1);
y=coord(:,2);
```